# YII session not working in Chrome Browser

Tags: yii

I am unable to login using chrome browser but it works perfectly in Firefox. I guess yii session is not working in chrome? may be?

Comment: Are you using yii-debug-toolbar extension ?

Comment: i have disabled yii debug and i have also set session.auto_start = 1 in my php.ini but still i am having the same problem

Comment: i am not using any yii-debug-toolbar extension

Comment: show code, i have same problem, and i solve it.

Comment: sessions not related to client browser , it's on server side ?
add your code to check .

Comment: It should not be so except if you're trying locally and your local domain is something like http://localhost/ and not http://site.local/. Having 2nd level is important.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are independent from browser - they are stored on server. Browser has access only to session id which he gets from server trough cookie or as link parameter